# View both site search and product search data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, site-search

Google analytics provides me with data of how the site search is used. 
 However, on our page we also have a separate search on products page (product search).

Is there is a way to get search data from the product search in the same way as I can get from site search from Google analytics?

Answer (score 1):

In the site search setup, you can specify up to 5 separate parameters used for site/product searches. Couldn't you specify one parameter for your site search and another parameter for your product search?

Details on implementation are here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en